# Trying to get percentage of total as a field

Tags: sql-server, group-by, percentage

I am trying to get a percentage of the total records in addition to the counts of each grouping.

For example, I have a query below where I get the count of the total records which qualify as "touched" and those that don't.

I then want to get the Percentage of the whole in terms of those counts (If 40/50 records are "touched" then it should show 80%)

N/A

```
SELECT COUNT(Contact) AS [COUNT],
       (CASE WHEN number>=1 THEN 'Touched' ELSE 'Not Touched' END) AS TOUCHED
FROM Events
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN number>=1 THEN 'Touched' ELSE 'Not Touched' END)

Count    TOUCHED
604      Not Touched
213      Touched
```

There should be an additional column with percentage showing 73.92% for "Not Touched" and 26.07% for "Touched"

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT() * 100 / SUM()` will return the percentage:

```
SELECT COUNT(Contact) AS COUNT,
    (CASE WHEN number >= 1 THEN 'Touched' ELSE 'Not Touched' END) AS TOUCHED,
    (COUNT(Contact) * 100 / SUM(Contact)) AS PERCENT
FROM Events
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN number >= 1 THEN 'Touched' ELSE 'Not Touched' END)
```

Comment: You *might* want to avoid the integer division here.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you're after:

```
SELECT COUNT(Contact) AS [COUNT],
       (COUNT(Contact) * 1.0) / COUNT(Contact) OVER () AS Perc,
       CASE WHEN number>=1 THEN 'Touched' ELSE 'Not Touched' END AS TOUCHED
FROM Events
GROUP BY CASE WHEN number>=1 THEN 'Touched' ELSE 'Not Touched' END;
```

You can use a Window to get the total outside of the group, and dovide the count by it.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it with something like:

```
Select ([Touched]/[Not touched])*100
From (
Your code

)
```

This can also be accomplished by inserting it into a temp table and doing the same thing with the columns.

You may have to cast/convert [touched] to a decimal.

Comment: The OP doesn't have 2 columns called `touched` and `[not touched]`, those are `varchar` values of the column `Touched`.

Comment: Ope missed that, good point. Guess id use a self join to separate it out into 2 columns then but it looks like everyone else has this.

Answer (score 0):

This version replaces the labels in your original query with column names instead. If you need inline labels, the changes should be simple:

```
SELECT 
    Touched,
    Cast(Touched/Cast(Total as decimal(9,2)) * 100.0 as Decimal(5,2)) as TouchedPct,
    Total - Touched as [Not Touched],
    Cast((Total - Touched)/Cast(Total as decimal(9,0)) * 100.0 as Decimal(5,2)) as NotTouchedPct
FROM (
    SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN number >= 1 then 1 else 0 END) as Touched,
        Count(*) as Total
    FROM Events
    ) src
```

Note that if `number` can never be negative, then the Touched calculation can be changed to

```
SUM(SIGN(number)) as Touched,
```